# Access sub sub page in Vue

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, axios

I've taken over a project that uses wordpress as a backend with wp-json and nuxt/vue as a frontend.

On a given page, there can be sub pages, and also sub sub pages.

I have no idea how to reach these.

The first level of sub pages are reached like this in vue:

```
computed: {
    hasSubMenu() {
        return this.child_pages && this.child_pages.length;
    }
}
```

I've tried to access the sub-sub pages as:

```
hasSubSubMenu() {
    return this.child_pages.child_pages && this.child_pages.child_pages.length;
}
```

But no dice.

If I can access the sub-sub pages in vue, I think I'm able to display them.

The whole script section on the page is this:

```
<script>
import api from '~/plugins/api';
import TopSlider from '~/components/blocks/TopSlider';
import ContentBlocks from '~/components/ContentBlocks';
import NewsList from '~/components/NewsList';
import PressList from '~/components/PressList';
import SubMenu from '~/components/SubMenu';
import SubSubMenu from '~/components/SubSubMenu';
import meta from '~/plugins/meta';

export default {
    mixins: [meta],
    components: {
        TopSlider,
        ContentBlocks,
        NewsList,
        PressList,
        SubMenu,
        SubSubMenu
    },
    asyncData(context) {
        return api.getCollection(context).catch((e) => {
            context.error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Not found' });
        });
    },
    computed: {
        hasSubMenu() {
            return this.child_pages && this.child_pages.length;
        },
        hasSubSubMenu() {
            return this.child_pages.child_pages && this.child_pages.child_pages.length;
        },
        childVisible() {
            return typeof this.$route.params.subpage !== 'undefined';
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the child components with `$children` prop.

For example:

```js
for (let child1 of this.$children) {
  console.log(child1.$options.name);
  for (const child2 of child1.$children) {
    console.log(child2.$options.name);
  }
}
```

But you have attention, because the `children` contain all sub-components and you must filter just sub-page components.

Comment: Hmm, this does not help me - can you provide more info on where I should put this? I need to parse the data to the vue fcomponent from page.vue

Comment: You can put this code in anywhere in your component parent. For example, if you need this information in the begin, you can put this code in `mounted` event. You can also put this code in computed property. Do you can understand?

Comment: No, sorry. Why are you writing this.$children, when it's referred to as: this.child_pages? Also - nuxt is giving me an unexpected console log...

Comment: I understood that pages are components, right? If this is truth, with `this.$children` you can access all sub-components. See the documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-children

Comment: Just posted the whole file. Pls note that pages are fetched from wordpress API.

Answer (score 0):

@gabriel: This is the complete page.vue file.

```
<template>
  <section>
        <top-slider class="slider" :class="{'with-menu': hasSubMenu}" :slides="slides"></top-slider>
        <sub-menu v-if="hasSubMenu" :base="slug" :base-title="title" :links="child_pages"></sub-menu>
        <nuxt-child></nuxt-child>
        <transition name="test">
            <content-blocks v-if="!childVisible" :blocks="contents"></content-blocks>
        </transition>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import api from '~/plugins/api';
import TopSlider from '~/components/blocks/TopSlider';
import ContentBlocks from '~/components/ContentBlocks';
import NewsList from '~/components/NewsList';
import PressList from '~/components/PressList';
import SubMenu from '~/components/SubMenu';
import meta from '~/plugins/meta';

export default {
    mixins: [meta],
    components: {
        TopSlider,
        ContentBlocks,
        NewsList,
        PressList,
        SubMenu
    },
    asyncData(context) {
        return api.getCollection(context).catch((e) => {
            context.error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Not found' });
        });
    },
    computed: {
        hasSubMenu() {
            return this.child_pages && this.child_pages.length;
        },
        childVisible() {
            return typeof this.$route.params.subpage !== 'undefined';
        }
    }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.slider {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    &.with-menu {
        margin-bottom: 60px;
    }
}
.test-enter-active, .test-leave-active {
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
.test-enter, .test-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

Below the sub menu, I need to add if the current page has sub pages.